# Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Hello I'm new in Angular js.I use Ng-Table module to add pegination,filter into table.But When I try to run following code it shows me sorting of undefined.However  I find out that params was not defined that's why it give me error sort of undefined.

```
$http({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/",
        dataType:'json',
        method:'GET',
        data:'',
        headers:{
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.tableData = response.data;
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 5
        }, {
            total: $scope.tableData.length,

            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                console.log(params);
                $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.tableData;

                $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;

                $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                $defer.resolve($scope.data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Question How I can make it work properly in angularjs1.6.1.js?**

When I put the following code it works perfect but without filter without sorting

```
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            page:1,
            count:5
        }, {
            getData: function(params) {
                params.total($scope.tableData.length);
                return $scope.tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Your `params` value is undefined, check why.

Comment: How I could check it @felixmosh

Comment: I find out I remove $defer from the first sample code then params works but I encounter with other problem which  $filter is not defined How I can solve this problem ?

Comment: I didn't inject the $filter dependency in the controller. I got the answer

Answer (score 1):

To use sorting in angularjs, you need to inject the $filter as a dependency

```
app.controller('TutorialController', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
```

Comment: I have one more question sir. 
                getData: function (params,$defer) {
                    console.log(params);
                    $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.tableData, params.orderBy()) : $scope.tableData;

                    $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;

                    $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                     $defer.resolve($scope.data);

                }

Comment: this code dosn't see $defer moreover When I try to inject it it give errors